# partial uniqueness of index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I want to have a DB table that will have (among other additional fields):

```
int id  
int group_id   
varchar(20) code  
int code_status
```

The codes are randomly generated and I would like to enforce uniqueness of the group_id+code within the scope of a specific code_status (e.g. 0).
i.e. to have `group_id+code where codes_staus=0` be unique.
so that for example it is o.k. to have:

```
id,group_id,code,code_status  
1,1,1,0  
2,1,2,0
```

because the codes are unique.
it should also be o.k. to have:

```
1,1,1,1  
2,1,1,1
3,1,1,0
```

because even though group+code are not unique its o.k. as long as the status is not 0.

But having

```
1,1,1,0
1,1,1,0
```

should not be permitted.

Can I use some form of indexes to force this type of partial uniqueness?
or should I just search for group_id+code+0 before any new insert?

I need this to work on MySQL but would also appreciate solutions that work on other DBs just for the purpose of expanding my knowledge.

Comment: Also consider `TRIGGER` and `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think this can be solved with indexes. You can't put an index on just some of the values of a column.

But you can solve it just with MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (group_id,code,code_status) 
    SELECT 1, 2, 0
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM your_table 
        WHERE group_id = 1 AND code= 2 AND code_status = 0
    )
```

And you may also need to do it for `UPDATE`.

---

**OR**

Have two tables. One for the `code_status = 0` (where you will be able to put your unique index) and one for the other, and create a view to merge them.

```
table_1
-----------------
int id  
int group_id   
varchar(20) code

table_2
-----------------
int id  
int group_id   
varchar(20) code
int code_status
```

And the view

```
CREATE VIEW all_codes AS 
SELECT id, group_id, code, 0 AS code_status FROM table_1 
UNION SELECT * FROM table_2
```

You'd get colliding ids, but that can be fixed by setting the autoincrement to use odd numbers for one of the tables and even for the other.

Comment: Thanks Alin, I don't think I can use the second method because it makes changing of the status_code too complicated. I will have to consider the first option and see if I can tell if a new line was added or not (I guess I should be able to tell based on the resulting rowCount).